# Can't make printf happy. Rejecting format strings of "i" and "l"

Tags: c, printf

```
long int triagedOut = 0;

printf("%i", triagedOut);
```

> main.c|89|warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but
> argument 2 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]|

I actually get that message twice for the same line.  ???

OK, so I will change it to the long int specifier "l" and, then...

```
printf("%l", triagedOut);
```

> main.c|89|warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]|
>
> main.c|89|warning: too many arguments for format
> [-Wformat-extra-args]|

And I get these two messages twice, too.

I don't even know how there could be too many of anything.  Just 1 of everything.  What's it trying to tell me?

Comment: If you want to print a long int number you should use `%li` to print it. [C types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

Comment: "*how there could be too many of anything*" What the compiler is telling you is that `"%l"` is not recognized as a valid format specifier, and without any such specifier the `triagedOut` argument passed into the call is one too many. Same warning as for `printf("hello world", triagedOut);` for example.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Or searching?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `%ld` for `long int`.

```
printf("%ld", triagedOut);
```

Note also these remarks:

- Format `%i` indeed expects an `int` argument, and you are passing a `long int`, which is a different type and may have a different size, depending on the target platform.
- Format `%l` is incomplete: `l` is just a *length modifier*, you also need a *conversion specifier* such as `i`, `d`, `u`, `x`... hence the proposed correction `%ld`. `i` and `d` are equivalent for `printf()`, but they have a different meaning for `scanf()`: `%i` converts an integer expressed in decimal, octal or hexadecimal as determined by its initial characters, whereas `%d` only converts an integer expressed in decimal.

  ```
   int i;
   sscanf("0x10", "%i", &i);  // sets i to 16
   sscanf("0x10", "%d", &i);  // sets i to 0
   sscanf("010", "%d", &i);   // sets i to 10
   sscanf("010", "%i", &i);   // sets i to 8
  ```
- The reason you get the messages twice might be that these are warning messages, not preventing the compilation from proceeding, and your IDE might compile 2 different versions of the executable, one in debug mode and one in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use %ld or %li instead of %l or %i for printing long integer.

```
long int triagedOut = 0;

printf("%li", triagedOut);
```